# Can not read group of null

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am testing with Karma Jasmin within Angular2 and in my example:

```
import {LoginComponent} from './login.component';

describe('Component: LoginComponent', ()=>{
    it('should have the title of "Login Cybercrime Analytics"', ()=>{
        const component = new LoginComponent(null, null, null, null);
        expect(component.title).toEqual("Login Cybercrime Analytics");
    });
});
```

I am getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of null

My loginservice is expecting following:

> (alias) new LoginComponent(fb: FormBuilder, router: Router, http:
>   Http, loginService: LoginService): LoginComponent import
>   LoginComponent

I didn't understand what is the problem. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: you are mixing all these test together to need to test your component with these integrations or alone if alone these mock these dependencies and test

Comment: Ok, can you tell me what do you mean with these integrations? I created now   let fb:FormBuilder;
    let http:Http;
    let router:Router; and passed it into LoginComponent but now it is group of undefined

Comment: Your external dependencies

Comment: ok, do you have an example. I have imported for example Formbuilder etc..Do I need a constructor as well?

Comment: If property is null, so probably object was not initialed. If property undefined - property has no value. Wouldn't think this is because of dependencies (unless that object comes from other libraries)